# Do Until loop Syntax error vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write this module to compute a letter grade from a % in the next cell over and loop through the rows until the row is empty. Whats wrong with the syntax of this code? I get error: Runtime error 438: Object doesnt support this property or method at `Average = Cells(i, 6).Valve`

```
Sub Grade()
Dim Average As Double
Dim i As Integer

i = 3

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 6))

Average = Cells(i, 6).Valve
Average = Average * 100

If (Average <= 60) Then
    Cells(i, 7).Valve = ("E")
End If
If (Average <= 70) Then
    Cells(i, 7).Valve = ("D")
End If
If (Average <= 80) Then
    Cells(i, 7).Valve = ("C")
End If
If (Average <= 90) Then
    Cells(i, 7).Valve = ("B")
End If
If (Average <= 100) Then
    Cells(i, 7).Valve = ("A")
End If

i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: do you mean `ElseIf`?

Comment: At what point do you assign a value to `Average`?

Comment: Made some changes I get a new error, Loop without Do

Comment: There is a typo in your code, .Valve should be .Value This is why you get the object doesn't support the method error

Comment: Fixed all the typos and updated the code, same error just new location

Comment: Have you tried my code?

Comment: Typo: you have `Average = Cells(i, 6).Valve` with a `v`, should be `Average = Cells(i, 6).Value` with a `u`

Comment: @Chris, there is more than one, EVERY Value is typed as Valve :)

Comment: Duraholiday you changed the wrong one, you change the only one that was correctly .Value to .Valve also. You need to do a little research on objects, properties and methods, Cells can have a Value, a formula or many other things, they can't have a Valve

Comment: Ughh, Yeah I see that now... Mechanical Engineer probs haha. Sorry guys.

Comment: All good mate, glad we could get it working for you :). Check the updated code in my post, condensed it down a bit more for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought on @zedfoxus post

Single line ifs don't need an end if

```
Sub Grade()
Dim Average As Double
Dim i As Long

i = 3

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 7))

    Average = Cells(i, 6).Value
    Average = Average * 100    
    If (Average < 60) Then Cells(i, 7).Value = ("E")
    If (Average < 70) Then Cells(i, 7).Value = ("D")
    If (Average < 80) Then Cells(i, 7).Value = ("C")
    If (Average < 90) Then Cells(i, 7).Value = ("B")
    If (Average < 100) Then Cells(i, 7).Value = ("A")

    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Further to this though, here is my take on the problem. I have put together a condensed routine using a 2 dimensional array and taking advantage of the worksheet function Vlookup. This works because it will find the closest thing (useful when you are using ranges of numbers)

```
Sub Grade()
Dim Average As Double, i As Long, MyArr As Variant
MyArr = Array(Array(60, "E"), Array(70, "D"), Array(80, "C"), Array(90, "B"), Array(100, "A"))
i = 3
Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 7))
    Average = Cells(i, 6).Value * 100 'Why * 100? Anyway just copied what you have done in your code
    Cells(i, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Average, MyArr, 2)
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

And lastly, because the Average variable is only used once, it doesn't really need to be there (whilst it could be argued the same for MyArr it would be too bloated to include in the Vlookup, it would become hard to read), you can remove it and just reference its makeup in the Vlookup to condense the code further, and finally, we can remove `i=3` and `i=i+1` by using a for next loop and polling to the last row of data like so:

```
Sub Grade()
Dim i as long, MyArr As Variant
MyArr = Array(Array(60, "E"), Array(70, "D"), Array(80, "C"), Array(90, "B"), Array(100, "A"))
For i = 3 To Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(i, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 6).Value * 100, MyArr, 2)
Loop
End Sub
```

I am not sure why you are multiplying by 100 and I don't have your test data. I made my own test data but had to remove the *100 to make it work, my data was in column F.

```
40  
50  
60  E
65  E
70  D
75  D
80  C
85  C
90  B
95  B
100 A
```

This is the code I used:

```
Sub Grade2()
Dim i As Long, MyArr As Variant
MyArr = Array(Array(60, "E"), Array(70, "D"), Array(80, "C"), Array(90, "B"), Array(100, "A"))
For i = 3 To Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(i, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 6).Value, MyArr, 2)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Because you have .Valve everywhere instead of .Value. You would be better off trying to understand the code I have given you and sticking with that as opposed to trying to get the bloated multiple if code working. Happy to help you if you want to make it work but it's not as efficient. Alternatively use the multiple if code I posted, that should work also.

Comment: You might want to debug the "fixed" version of the OPs code.  Not only won't it work if the grade column is empty (column 7), but if is does run it gives everybody an A

Comment: Yeah i started to use it today and this issue happens. If the grade for example is 75 then it will put C then it will go to the next if statement and sees that its less then 80 and changes it to B and then A... how can i get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Dim Average As Double
i As Integer
```

to

```
Dim Average As Double
Dim i As Integer

or

Dim Average As Double, i As Integer

or

Dim Average As Double, _
i As Integer
```

Your code needs a little more work. Use something like this:

```
Sub Grade()
Dim Average As Double
Dim i As Integer

i = 3

Do Until IsEmpty(Cells(i, 7))

    Cells(i, 6).Value = Average
    ' Perhaps the above should be 
    ' Average = Cells(i,6).Value

    If (Average < 60) Then
        Cells(i, 7).Valve = ("E")
    End If
    If (Average < 70) Then
        Cells(i, 7).Valve = ("D")
    End If
    If (Average < 80) Then
        Cells(i, 7).Valve = ("C")
    End If
    If (Average < 90) Then
        Cells(i, 7).Valve = ("B")
    End If
    If (Average < 100) Then
        Cells(i, 7).Valve = ("A")
    End If

    i = i + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you want to use Formula instead of VBA.

Vlookup can do this. As below, hope this help.

[image]